# What is the correct way to veriy if an user exist in my amplify app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm asking this question because when you add auth to amplify project it uses cognito, and the user can sign up and sign in. But should I do something when the user sign up? I mean databasewise? Because let's say I have a route and only a person who is logged in can access? how am i supposed to log in the user? By cognito or dynamodb? For example let's say I want to list all users that signed up in my website. the only way i can get this information is if i save the user info on dynamodb when the signed up for the first time? and from that point on, do i check dynamodb or cognito to check authz? let's say professor vs student?. I'm asking this because I had the same problem with firebase, when I enabled login with google I saved user info on database, but I'm not sure if this the right thing to do, because everytime this user logs in I checked if he was already in the database otherwise I added him

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read the Amplify docs where it discusses how users can sign up, sign in and sign out:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signIn() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
}
```

There is not need for DynamoDB as Amplify via Cognito will handle all your auth needs.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question I would like to know how to differentiate a user from another rg teacher vs student, because when using amplify the only thing it asks is a username